# Differentiating the Riemannian exponential map with respect to the base point

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, coordinate-systems, geodesic

> If $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold, $\alpha \in \Omega^1 M$ a smooth $1$-form, $x \in M$ and $y$ in a normal coordinates neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, how should I proceed in differentiating $y \mapsto \alpha_y (\exp_y ^{-1} (x))$ with respect to $y$? (I am interested in the gradient and the Laplacian of this function.)

If differentiating were with respect to $x$, I would know what to do (perform the computation in normal coordinates around $x$), but how to deal with the argument being the base point of $\exp$, so that for each $y$ there exists a different set of normal coordinates?

Comment: Will it help to rewrite from the view point of $x$? I.e. $\alpha_y(Dexp_x(exp^{-1}_x(y)))$

Comment: Having pondered, I agree with @MemeboyInc. Pull back by $\exp_x$ and note (I think!) that $\exp_y^{-1}(x) = -(\exp_x)_*(\exp_x^{-1}(y))$. So you'll have to start by computing $\exp_x^*\alpha$.

Comment: Ah yes, the negative sign from following the geodesic backwards. Very clumsy series of comments on my part

Comment: @TedShifrin: Notice that $-(\exp_x)_* (\exp_x ^{-1} (y))$ is merely a linear map $: T_x M \to T_y M$, so it cannot equate the vector $\exp_y ^{-1} (x) \in T_y M$. I agree, though, that there exists $v \in T_x M$ such that $-(\exp_x)_* (\exp_x ^{-1} (y)) (v) = \exp_y ^{-1} (x)$, namely $v = [-(\exp_x)_* (\exp_x ^{-1} (y))] ^{-1} (\exp_y ^{-1} (x))$. For obvious reasons, I wouldn't know what to do with such a beast...

Comment: @MemeboyInc.: Please see my above answer to Ted Shiffrin.

Comment: Wait. $(\exp_x)_*$ is the linear map. I've applied it to a specific tangent vector (quite as you did in your original set-up). I'm confused. What Memeboy and I are both thinking is that the geodesic from $y$ to $x$ runs backward from $x$ to $y$, whence my claim.

Comment: @TedShifrin: This is how I understand things: $\exp_x$ is $: T_x M \to M$, taking $\exp_x ^{-1} (y)$ to $y$. It follows that $\mathrm d (\exp_x) (\exp_x ^{-1} (y))$ goes from $T_{\exp_x ^{-1} (y)} T_x M$ to $T_y M$. I believe that you use $(\exp_x)_*$ for $\mathrm d (\exp_x)$. (I have dropped the minus sign for clarity.)

Comment: We're having a notation disagreement. (This is why I worked in complex geometry, not Riemannian!! :P) I'm suppressing the point in $T_xM$ where you evaluate the derivative. It really should be $(\exp_x)_{*q}$ where $q=\exp_x^{-1}(y)$. I'm interpreting the tangent space at that point as $T_pM$, and I'm feeding to the derivative the tangent vector $-\exp_x^{-1}(y)$. Or something very much like this ...